# How do the sniper and marksman rifle bipods work?

Tags: battlefield-2042

In previous titles you could see the bipod being used when lying down or standing near a flat surface at firing height. In Battlefield 2042 I don't see any visual indication the bipod is being used.

Do I need to press a button or is it applied automatically and invsibly? If so, in what situations is it applied to the aiming characteristics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, the bipod should deploy automatically, but when I use the bipod, it sometimes doesn't deploy properly (I'm assuming it's a bug.)

After several attempts, I was able to confirm that the bipod deploys just like any other underbarrel attachment (such as laser sight, flashlight, GL, Masterkey), by pressing the key to use the attachment.

If you're on console(PS4/5, Xbox), hold down(↓) on your D-pad. If you're on PC, just simply hit X on your keyboard.

Comment: The OP is asking how the bipod is visible in the UI, active and not.

Comment: @DrFish How so? they weren't visible in BF3/4/Hardline/1/V either, if I recall correctly. I assumed OP meant they aren't visibly changed its stance (well, it's actually changes stance a little bit), like this [screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/LmXLjMv) I just took. How did you assume OP meant UI?

Comment: Searched a little bit, at least Battlefield 4 [doesn't have bipod UI.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMOLsm3Qxpc)

Comment: Little bit more, [Battlefield 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wK7XcF0DLY) [Battlefield V](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4v6suEpwe_w) doesn't have it either.